# Injecting global variables while testing copy the actual object, need the same instance

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webpack, babeljs

i'm running a test with mocha, chai and sinon, the main purpose is to mock localStorage and inject it as a global variable, so i can call it later as `localStorage`. The main issue is that i'm using webpack with babel using the node strategy for testing (for faster testing and dev), so i'm using rewire to overwrite the globals.

This is my code:

```
import assert from 'assert';
import rewire from 'rewire';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import todos from './mocks/todos';
import LocalStorage from './mocks/localStorage.js';
let Todo = rewire('../src/store/todo');


let todo,
    localStorage,
    localStorageMock,
    task = { id: 5, title: 'new task', completed: false };

describe('Todo Model', () => {

  beforeEach(function() {
    localStorage     = new LocalStorage();
    localStorageMock = sinon.mock(localStorage);
    Todo.__set__('globals.localStorage', localStorage);
    todo             = new Todo();
  });

  describe('add todo', () => {
    it('save the todo to localStorage',()  =>{
      localStorageMock.expects('setItem').once();
      todo.create(task);
      localStorageMock.verify();
      expect(localStorage.data['todos']).to.be.a('string');
    });

  });
});
```

**EDIT**

here is the todo module

```
import _ from 'ramda';
import {Maybe} from 'ramda-fantasy';

let log = (x, y) => console.log(x, y);

// getItem :: storage, item -> string
let getItem = _.curry((storage, x) => storage.getItem(x));

// parse :: string -> json
let parse = (x) => x ? JSON.parse(x): null;

// stringify :: json -> string
let stringify = (x) => JSON.stringify(x);

// setItem :: storage, string, jsonStringified
let setItem = _.curry((storage, x, y) => storage.setItem(x, y));

export default class todo {

  constructor(){
    this.name = 'name';
    this.storage = localStorage;
    this.storage.getItem('todos') ? '' : this.storage.setItem('todos', '');
  }

  create(todo) {
    this.new = _.compose(_.map(_.compose(setItem(this.storage, 'todos'), stringify, _.append(todo), parse)), Maybe, getItem(this.storage));
    this.new('todos');
  }

}
```

The test fails because `setItem` is never called, but in the code is called. If u return the instance of localStorage and compare it with my mock `localStorageMock === returnedLocalStorage` gives me false.

This is because rewire copy each method separately creating a new object.

When i change the beforeEach block:

```
Todo.__set__('globals.localStorage', localStorage);
```

to

```
Todo.__set__('localStorage', localStorage);
```

it throws a referenceError:

```
1) Todo Model "before each" hook for "have a create method":
     ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
      at Function.eval (eval at __set__ (src/store/todo.js:18:26), <anonymous>:1:14)
      at Function.__set__ (src/store/todo.js:18:26)
      at Context.<anonymous> (spec/index.spec.js:18:5)
```

How do you test if a service with a global dependency was called?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant code from the Todo module?

Comment: Have the same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that your Todo module references `localStorage`, but you're rewiring `global.localStorage`. In the [rewire README](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire/blob/851c1032dcf4b15a251eef06e9f10b57a57bc31c/README.md) the example for mocking globals uses the names `process` and `console`, not `globals.process` or `globals.console`. Rewire isn't "smart" enough (by design, I assume) to know that they're the same thing. You need to use the exact name that's used in your module. With that in mind, I think what you want is this:

```
Todo.__set__('localStorage', localStorage);
```

P.S. In this case I think rewire might be overkill. Since your module's constructor does `this.storage = localStorage`, you could just spy on `todo.storage`:

```
todo = new Todo();
sinon.spy(todo.storage, 'setItem');
```

#### Edit

I *think* the ReferenceError happens because, unlike `console` and `process` in the example, `localStorage` doesn't already exist in Node.js. My knowledge of rewire is incomplete, however, so there could be another answer.

I think the simplest fix is to just create it in the global context (which also doesn't need rewire):

```
describe('Todo Model', () => {
  beforeEach(function() {
    localStorageMock = sinon.mock(new LocalStorage());
    global.localStorage = localStorageMock; // <-- set it here
    todo = new Todo();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    delete global.localStorage; // <-- clean up here
  });

  // ...
});
```

It's kind of ugly, but it's also dead simple.

Comment: I've tried this, but the test fails with a reference error, i will update the question.

Comment: About the ps, i still need to inject the localStorage as a global so i can maintain the functions pure.